# How to limit return type

Tags: typescript, types, string-literals

I have this literal type:

```
export const MyType = [
  'one',
  'two',
  'three',
  'four'
] as const;

export type MyType = typeof MyType[number];
```

I have a function typeof `MyType`

```
function myFunc(): MyType {}
```

Say I want to limit `myFunc()` to just two options `'one'` and `'two'` that are partof `MyType`, is there anyway to do so?

e.g `function myFunc(): 'one' and 'two from MyType  {}`

Comment: Does `typeof MyType[0] | typeof MyType[1]` work?

Comment: You can write `function myFunc(): 'one' | 'two'` explicitly; if you want it to programmatically depend on `MyType`, you need to say how, because [there are lots of ways to think about this with just this one example](https://tsplay.dev/mpDaxm).  Could you provide some guidance here?

Comment: @jcalz thank you for that info, that is awesome, the extract works for me, would you add that palygorund code example as an answer? I would wish there would be some validation when you specify things like `Extract<MyType, 'one' | 'two'>` to validate typos

Comment: "I would wish there would be some validation when you specify things like `Extract<MyType, 'one' | 'two'>` to validate typos".  Could you please [edit] the question and example code to show use cases you'd like to see pass and fail?  Right now you still haven't quite eplained what you're looking for, but this "validate typos" thing seems promising.  My guess is something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZapeN).  Am I right?  If so, you should probably make the question explicit about what you need, and I'd be happy to write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was released in version 1.8 as "string literal types"

[What's New in Typescript - String Literal Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#string-literal-types)

```
export const MyType = [
  'one',
  'two',
  'three',
  'four'
] as const;

export type MyType = typeof MyType[number];

function myFunc(): "one"|"two"{
  return "one"
}
```

You can also use your array in the return value

```
function myFunc(): typeof MyType[0] | typeof MyType[1]{
  return "one"
}
```